# Tabela em html com colunas desalinhadas

Tags: php, html, tabela-html, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho essa tabela:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é possível reparar, as colunas não estão alinhadas com as linhas, e eu não sei pq e não sei como arrumar, já q smp fiz desta forma e nunca tive esse problema.

Segue o codigo da tabela:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Atividade<th>
    <th>Usuario</th>
    <th>Data/Horario</th>
</tr>

    <?php
$a = 0; $b = 0;
while($a < 10){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$tabela[$a][$b].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$tabela[$a][$b+1].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$tabela[$a][$b+2].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
$a++;
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Tem  algum  arquivo ou  codifo css em  seu  site ?  provavelmente deve estar mudando as propriedades da tabela, bom recomendo usar bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem uma falta de fechamento do primeiro `th` que está distorcendo as colunas:

```
<th>Atividade<th>
              ↑
```

Altere para:

```
<th>Atividade</th>
              ↑
```

Comment: Deixei essa passar kkk, valeu cara

Comment: Isso acontece nas melhores familias. rs Abs!!